# Integrate Azure DevOps Server Repos with Azure DevOps Service Boards

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to integrate an Azure DevOps Server repository with Azure DevOps Services Boards?

This way the commits and branches can be linked to the development section of the related user stories.

Comment: What is your use-case here? Why not just choose one platform and stick with it?

Comment: It has been decided to keep the Repositories on premise for security reasons.